# Enable Bluetooth HCI Snoop Log by adb command

Tags: android, debugging, bluetooth, adb, remote-debugging

I want to know what is the **adb command** for enable the Bluetooth HCI snoop log. I already know that **adb pull/sdcard/btsnoop_hci.log** command is used for retrieving the FILE. but, i want to know the adb command for enable the snoop log. please help me..

Comment: any one know the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use

```
adb shell settings put secure bluetooth_hci_log 1
```